# Error while commenting

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have a page that gets posts from a database and shows the posts in a page that I have named as *news-feed.php*. And my page looks like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../Style/news_feed.css"> <!-- Styling -->
<div class="whole-container">
<?php

$connection = mysqli_connect($server_name, $database_username, $database_password, $database_name); //The variables are defined in the **backbone.php** page that we have previously included...
$sql = "SELECT * FROM posts";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    showPosts($row["posted_date"], $row["author"], $row["type"], $row["body"], $row["comments"], $row["id"]);
}





function get($property){ //It gets the $_SESSION["id"] and gets other info about the user using the id.
  require '../includes/backbone.php';
  $connection = mysqli_connect($server_name, $database_username, $database_password, $database_name);
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '" . $_SESSION["id"] . "'";
  $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $outcome = $row[$property];
  }
  return $outcome;
}





function showPosts($date, $author, $type, $body, $comments, $id) {
  ?>
  <div class="post">
    <div class="poster"><a href="user.php/<?php echo $author ?>"> <b id="author"><?php echo $author . " posted a new " . $type . ""; ?></a></b> <b id="date"> <?php echo $date ?> </b></div>
    <div class="body"><p><?php echo $body ?></p></div>
    <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">
      <?php
      if($type === "query"){
        enableComment();
        if(isset($_POST["postComment"]) && !empty($_POST["comment"])){
          postComment(get("full_name"), date("h:sa"), $_POST["comment"], $id);
      }
      }?>
     <button id="showComments" name="showComments"><i class="fa fa-sort-desc"></i> Show comments</button>
      </form>
    <div class="comments">
      <?php
      if(isset($_POST["showComments"])){
        echo $comments;
      }
      ?>
    </div>
  </div>
  <style>
  .post{
    width: 40%;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    margin-left: 20%;
    margin-top: 2.5%;
    border: 0.2px solid #dddfe2;
    padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
    max-height: 80%;
    min-height: 20%;
    overflow: auto;
  }
  .poster{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 20%;
    max-height: 20%;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
  }
  .poster #author{
    float: left;
    font-family: helvetica;
    font-size: 13px;
  } 
  .poster #date{
    float: right;
    font-family: arial;
    color: grey;
    font-size: 13px;
  }
  .post .body{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    float: left;
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
    max-height: 40%;
  }
  .post .body p{
    font-family: helvetica;
  }
  .post #showComments{
    width: 30%;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family: helvetica;
    color: #3b5998;
  }
  .post #showComments i{
    color: purple;
  }
  .post .comments{
    width: 60%;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    height: 39%;
    max-height: 40%;
    overflow: auto;
    margin-top: 1%;
  }
  .post .comments b{
    font-weight: normal;
    font-family: helvetica;
  }
  #comment{
    width: 50%;
    margin-left: 20%;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-bottom: 0.2px solid #dddfe2;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
    border-top: none;
    height: 20px;
    padding-left: 10px;
  }
  #commentButton{
    width: 10%;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #dddfe2;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: #3b5998;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  #comment:focus{
    outline-width: 0px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dddfe2;
  }
    </style>
<?php
} ?>



<?php
function enableComment() {
  ?>
  <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">
  <input name="comment" type="text" placeholder="Wanna Help?" id="comment">
  <button name="postComment" type="submit" id="commentButton"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i></button>
    </form>
    <?php
}


function postComment($author, $time, $comment, $id){
  require '../includes/backbone.php';
  $connection = mysqli_connect($server_name, $database_username, $database_password, $database_name);
  $sql = "UPDATE posts SET comments = \"'" . $author . "' -> '". $comment . "' @ '".$time . "'\" WHERE id = ". $id. "";
  echo $sql;
}


?>
```

Almost all the code works fine and whenever I load the page all the content from the database gets shown. But when I comment on a post, all other posts get commented which has the type of 'query'. So, How do I fix it?

I guess it is due to the while loop with which the posts are shown but if I put a break statement all other posts are not shown so how do I do it?

Please help...

Comment: So you saved a page having `html`, `css`, `php` as `.css` page

Comment: You show your posts in `news-feed.css` ??

Comment: At the bottom of your page the `UPDATE posts` query has `" '` these in it, and it seems like there are to many and they are not well looked after. You should recheck those `" '`

Comment: Those are just to clarify the data as strings!

Answer (score 10):

In the 1st line of code you have this comment tag :

`<!-- Styling !>`

You should change that to `<!-- Styling -->` which is the correct syntax to comment out lines of code in HTML, see the [documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_comment.asp).

The second problem would be that your page is saved as `.css`, it should be saved as `.php`.

Comment: @MukeshAryal you should not edit the code after things have been fixed, this can give miscomunication in the future with new people looking at this question